# Understanding the xmlns attribute in an Android layout

Tags: android

I have only recently had to set the xmlns attribute in an Android layout file. Initially when I was adding a third-party control, certain attributes in the control's XML didn't have a prefix to identify the namespace. When I ran my app, the control was displayed but those attributes that didn't have the namespace prefix were ignored. Only after adding the xmlns to the top of my file and adding the prefix to the attributes did those attributes get recognized at run time. Here is what the corrected code looks like:

```
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/ivFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_fab_star"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/pink_500"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/pink_100"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        />
```

The xmlns prefix her is 'fab'. What I don't understand is that without the namespace and prefix, the app compiles without any errors. Why doesn't Android Studio complain that it cannot find fab_icon? Why does it just ignore these attributes? I have seen a number of posts throughout stackoverflow on different topics where someone has indicated to leave out the prefix and then the code worked. So I'm at a loss to understand what's going on. In some problems (like mine) having the prefix is required but in others it isn't? Is this an issue with different versions of Android Studio or the SDK versions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Even you can define your own custom layout attributes.

> **Step 1:** Create a subclass of a view.

```
class PieChart extends View {
    public PieChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```

> **Step 2:** Define Custom Attributes with `<declare-styleable>` in `res/values/attrs.xml` .

```
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="PieChart">
       <attr name="showText" format="boolean" />
       <attr name="labelPosition" format="enum">
           <enum name="left" value="0"/>
           <enum name="right" value="1"/>
       </attr>
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

> **Step 3:** Using those attributes inside your layout xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customviews">
 <com.example.customviews.charting.PieChart
     custom:showText="true"
     custom:labelPosition="left" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> **Step 4:** Applying custom attributes to your view.

```
public PieChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
   TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
        attrs,
        R.styleable.PieChart,
        0, 0);

   try {
       mShowText = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PieChart_showText, false);
       mTextPos = a.getInteger(R.styleable.PieChart_labelPosition, 0);
   } finally {
       a.recycle();
   }
}
```

> **Step 5:** Adding properties and events
>
> Attributes are a powerful way of controlling the behavior and appearance of views, but they can only be read when the view is initialized. To provide dynamic behavior, expose a property getter and setter pair for each custom attribute. The following snippet shows how `PieChart` exposes a property called `showText`

```
public boolean isShowText() {
   return mShowText;
}

public void setShowText(boolean showText) {
   mShowText = showText;
   invalidate();
   requestLayout();
}
```

For more information and details, read this [link](http://see%20this%20[link][1].).

Comment: My question wasn't about HOW to create custom attributes. It was about understanding the need or lack thereof of using the xmlns attribute and the prefix that goes on attributes.

Comment: if you know how to create the custom view with attributes, then it simple to understand need or lack of those attributes. now consider if you have one custom attribute which is mandatory, what will happen if you dont provide it? will your view will get initialised?